# What is the right way to call com.google.common.collect.Lists.cartesianProduct()?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I am trying to call com.google.common.collect.Lists.cartesianProduct(...), but I keep getting a `NoSuchMethodError`. I would happily use either the [version that expects a List of Lists as an argument](https://guava.dev/releases/25.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.List-) or the [version that expects an array of Lists](https://guava.dev/releases/25.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.List...-), as long as it works.

What am I doing wrong?

#### Attempt 1:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
...
List<List<MyClass>> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
... //filling the List of Lists
List<List<MyClass>> product = Lists.cartesianProduct(candidates);
```

Result: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List com.google.common.collect.Lists.cartesianProduct(java.util.List)'`

When evaluating the expression in the debugger, the result is: `Type does not implement selector cartesianProduct and signature (Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;`

#### Attempt 2:

```
List<List<MyClass>> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
... //filling the List of Lists
List<MyClass>[] candidatesArray = candidates.toArray(new List[0]);
List<List<MyClass>> product = Lists.cartesianProduct(candidates);
```

Result: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List com.google.common.collect.Lists.cartesianProduct(java.util.List[])'`

Debugger evaluation: `Type does not implement selector cartesianProduct and signature ([Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;`

#### Attempt 3:

```
List<List<MyClass>> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
... //filling the List of Lists
List<List<MyClass>> product = Lists.cartesianProduct(candidates.get(0), candidates.get(1));
```

Result: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List com.google.common.collect.Lists.cartesianProduct(java.util.List[])'`

Debugger evaluation: `Type does not implement selector cartesianProduct and signature ([Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;`

Comment: Looks like it only takes a list of lists. Try attempt 3, but only pass in `candidates`.

Comment: The method expects a list of lists. As in the first approach. Theoretically, you can call it with a simple list (i.e. not a nested one), but it would be pointless. Your error messages seem to have their cause somewhere else. Provide a minimal reproducible example if you think the cause is in the way you call the method.

Comment: Sounds like you have a build problem. Since this method came in Guava v2, I'd bet you have the ancient predecessor, Google Collections, as a dependency somehow and that is resolved on the classpath first.

Comment: @BenManes You're right. The Maven POM had a guava-osgi dependency. Apparently this is an ancient project that was discontinued. I guess that because the Guava classes now come from a different Maven group id, Eclipse didn't warn me about the dependency conflict. If you'd like to post your solution as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as the right one.